# Inconsistent read write speed with external hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, python

I have a python script that takes a large file, reads it row by row, processes each line and finally dumps the processed line in a new file.
I print the time taken for the operation after every 500 lines. The problem is 2-3 weeks ago processing a file took 20 minutes. Processing the same file now takes > 2 hours. I am pretty sure I haven't changed the code. The RAM usage for this python script stays under 40-50% of my RAM (8 GiB). Is there a way I could figure out what might be going wrong or the steps I should take to figure out the problem?

(This is a pet project that requires large amount of data and hence the use of external hard disk)

Comment: Best guess, fragmentation.

Comment: Please tell us which filesystem you have on that external drive, and any other device your script does access - e.g.if the source data is on a fragmented drive that might also at least contribute to the problem. The amount of data handled, and how much of the disk that is used might also be part of the problem.